# Zoom automation parameters?

Tags: ableton-live

I have a MAX4Live plugin running that controls parameters via LFO. When I want to automatize the LFO offset (-100% to +100%), the automation track gets huge and I have to scroll for ages. Is it possible to zoom out so that I have a better overview over the automation curve?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). It would be far better addressed to Ableton's support channels.

Comment: @Tetsujin then what's the point of this site having 'ableton-live' keyword.

Comment: Tags are created by users; it takes far more effort & discussion to have one removed than to add one. All SE sites have 'good' & 'bad' tags; the busy ones have a constant stream of cleanup tasks. The quiet ones will never be able to get around to it.

Comment: uhm... lol what...?